# mouseout() not firing on disappearing objects

Tags: angular, mouseover, mouseleave

The following is happening (see gif)

1. I show a fontawesome icon that changes on `mouseenter()` and `mouseout()`
2. Clicking a button hides the icons and makes new elements appear.
3. Going back and making the old elements appear, the mouse technically never "left" the icons, so the fontawesome icon for the hovering state is still displayed.

Isn't there a way to have `mouseout()` firing whenever an element disappears? Because logically, the mouse isn't hovering that element anymore then

[image]

Here is the code, changing the icons is done by replacing the fontawesome prefix.

```
<div (mouseover)="ratingEmojis.right='fas'" (mouseout)="ratingEmojis.right='far'" (click)="this.state.jumpToConfigStep(100)" class="iconButton"> 
  <fa-icon style='pointer-events: none' [icon]="[ratingEmojis.right, 'frown-open']" size="6x" ></fa-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Try [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event instead of `mouseout`: `(blur)="ratingEmojis.right='far'"`

Comment: Unfortunately, the (blur) event is not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `this.state.jumpToConfigStep(100)` does but you could do this:

```
<div (mouseover)="ratingEmojis.right='fas'" (mouseout)="ratingEmojis.right='far'" (click)="rightClicked()" class="iconButton"> 
  <fa-icon style='pointer-events: none' [icon]="[ratingEmojis.right, 'frown-open']" size="6x" ></fa-icon>
</div>
```

```
rightClicked() {
   this.ratingEmojis.right = 'frown-open';
   this.state.jumpToConfigStep(100)
}
```

Though most of this looks like it could be achieved with css and `:hover`

Comment: unfortunately I have to change the whole fontawesome icon, if it would be just a color or so I could indeed have done it in CSS. Essentially I did it in the way you proposed, too.

Comment: Probably could use a refactor somehow then :) anyways if this does work for you can you approve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to default icon when onclick is fired

Comment: strange enough, I noticed only now that the original issue appears only on the right icon however, this solution worked, although there should be a more elegant way to do this imho.